# Highcharts pie spacing title - chart - legend

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart, spacing

I've created this pie chart: http://jsfiddle.net/r9wtfwzy/.

The size of elements is the way I want, but the spacement is too big.

- I tried changing margins:

  ```
  marginTop:-150,
  marginBottom:0,
  ```

But it whether approaches the title or the legend,it depends on which margin I change.

- If reduce the height, the chart decreases.
- If I change the size (e.g. 200%) in plotOptions, when there is less itens in the legend the chart gets too big, as you can see below.
  [image]

I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Use [size](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.size) parameter and [center](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.center)

Comment: @SebastianBochan I'm not sure about what you meant, but I added an image ilustrating the problem I face when changing the 'size' property.

Comment: ok so what is wrong in the first image?

Comment: @SebastianBochan nothing at all. However, the number of itens in the legend is variable, so if I set things (size: 200%) to be good for 8 elements, when I have 6 elements the chart looks too big.

Comment: You are right, anyway the solitin with size/center parameter doesnt work in your case? Can you replicate this issue as live demo ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan as you can see in the jsfiddle example, there is no problem with the size, so I could, as you suggest, change the 'center'attibute. However, this way I could only get it closer to the title OR the legend, not both at the same time.

Comment: Have you consdered to use y parameter in the legend: http://jsfiddle.net/r9wtfwzy/1/ ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan It has the exactly same effect as changing height.      The spacement looks less absurd , but that is because the chart shrunk.

Comment: When you adapt size, and move legend, chart is not shrinked,as I see.

Comment: @SebastianBochan  In my project, this chart is inserted among tables. If I pick the fiddle you sent, and change size to '150%' and y to '-300' the chart itself looks perfect. However, we can see  'highcharts' written far away from the end of the legend, in my project this means I have a huge space between the charts and the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not the perfect solution, since the spacement is still big sometimes, but what I ended up doing was to chose the appropriate parameters to a given situation and I changed the height depending on the number of elements in the legend:

```
$height_graph = 400 +20*$n_elements_legend;
```